# Conditional logic optimization: How to check against multiple unique cases in 1 line?

Tags: php

Here is a bit of code that displays: 'varname: varvalue' in a browser.  It is used by calling the vc('varname'); or vc(array('multiple','varnames'));

I first tried writing:

```
if (gettype($$var_string) == ('string' || 'boolean' || 'integer' || 'double')){}
```

however this didn't work.  The second group simplifies to true, and it always passed the conditional check.

So, I wrote out each check separately.  I'm new to coding, I'm sure there's an easier way, not sure what it would be.  I haven't had any luck searching here or google.  (probably not using the right jargon).  Thanks in advance.  - Mike

Oh, this is PHP, btw.  The problem in question applies to any language thou.

```
define('LB', '<br />');
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = array('mike', 'lewis', 'is', 'awesome');

function vc($var_string) {
    if (!is_array($var_string)){
    $var_string = array($var_string);
    }
foreach ($var_string as $var_string){
    global $$var_string;
    if (    (gettype($$var_string) == 'string') || 
            (gettype($$var_string) == 'boolean') || 
            (gettype($$var_string) == 'integer') || 
            (gettype($$var_string) == 'double') ) {
        print('<strong>'. $var_string . ': </strong>' . $$var_string . LB);        
    } elseif (  (gettype($$var_string) == 'array') || 
                (gettype($$var_string) == 'object') || 
                (gettype($$var_string) == 'resource')){
        print('<strong>' . $var_string . ': </strong>');
        print_r($$var_string);
        print(LB);
    }
} 
}

vc('var1');
vc('var2');
vc(array('var1', 'var2'));
```

Comment: Tip 1: Give functions and variables meaningful names to indicate what they do/represent. You'll thank yourself for it in the future :)

Comment: vc means 'var check', i wanted something quick to type :)

Comment: You know that now, but we don't and you'll forget very quickly. Trawling through code with variable/function names that are meaningless is hard. Code you post to ask for help on should be as clear as possible with good variable/function names so you make it easier for those who may wish to help you.

Comment: Tip 2: Don't use variable variables, for the love of Cthulhu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if( in_array($variable_to_test, Array("option1", "option2", "option3"))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `if ( in_array( gettype($$var_string) , array('string', 'boolean', 'integer', 'double') ) )`  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch/case statement instead of if/else. Letting it fall through should easily do the trick.

So:

```
switch( gettype($$var_string) ) {
  case 'string':
  case 'boolean':
  ...
    print('<strong>'. $var_string . ': </strong>' . $$var_string . LB);
    break;
  case 'array':
  case 'object':
  ...
    print('<strong>' . $var_string . ': </strong>');
    print_r($$var_string);
    print(LB);
    break;
}
```

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for more info.

Comment: That would work, I like the above option better :).  Thank you though.